# Pass current post title to a predefined link

Tags: custom-field, options

I have custom link option which I show on all posts using:

`<?php echo get_option('_custom_link'); ?>`

and let's say, I have defined it with a URL value of `http://somelink.com/?ref=title_of_current_post`, where `title_of_current_post` is replaced with the corresponding title of the post where the link was clicked.

Is it possible to do something like a placeholder tag e.g. `?ref=%%title%%`?

I'm still trying out a few things, just wanted to know if someone else had done something similar and share their solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's possible to use a placeholder tag, the following is the PHP code using a `_custom_link` value of `http://somelink.com/?ref=%%title%%`.

```
<?php
// must be within the Loop
$ref_slug = strtoupper(sanitize_title_with_dashes(get_the_title()));
$regex = '(\%\%title\%\%)';
$ref_link = ( get_option('_custom_link') ) ? preg_replace( $regex, $ref_slug, get_option('_custom_link')) : null;
echo $ref_link;
?>
```